# How to press a button after successful Ajax?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

When Ajax call is successful, user gets redirected to main page:

```
$('#button_1').on('click', function () {
                //code
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/somewhere",
                    data: {
                        //code
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                        location.href = "/";
                });    
            });
```

After getting redirected, I want to automatically click another button, which opens a modal. I tried inside `done` function different methods:

```
.done(function () {
    location.href = "/";
    $('#button_2').click(); // doesn't work 
 }); 

.done(function () {
    location.href = "/";
    setTimeout(function ()
        $('#button_2').click(); // doesn't execute  
    }, 2000);
 });

.done(function () {
    location.href = "/";
    $(document).ready( function () {
        // executes but user is immediately redirected to main page
        $('#button_2').click(); 
    });
 });
```

I also tried outside Ajax, in the function that Ajax call is in, but had the same results.

How can I click the button programmatically after the Ajax call?

Comment: try the `success:` attribute in ajax

Comment: is the `$('#button_2')` in the `/` page ?

Comment: If you redirect the user to another page, you can't do it in the first page. You have to do it on the second (redirected) page.

Comment: You'll have to put that click logic in the targetted page (at `/`)

Comment: @Satpal yes, I tried that and `.trigger('click')`. They work, but then user is immediately redirected to main page.

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui yes it is

Comment: I am saying that all the methods above work, but the end result is the main page, not the button that I want to click.

Comment: keep in mind that `done` will be executed regardless of the success or failure of the ajax call. you might want to start using `success` instead.
Also, don't invoke `click` on a button, see what logic you should be calling instead and call it straight from your success handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers. I researched a bit more and found another way to do it:

```
$('#button_1').on('click', function () {
                sessionStorage.setItem("reload", "true");
                //code
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/somewhere",
                    data: {
                        //code
                    }
                }).done(function () {
                        location.reload();
                });    
            });
```

And in main page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var reload = sessionStorage.getItem("reload");
        if (reload == "true") {
            $("#button_2").click();
            sessionStorage.setItem("reload", false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add that logic in the target (main) page.

Once you redirect, the current page is not longer the active one and all logic is removed.

You could add some parameter to the URL in order to know when you are there due to redirection, something like:

```
location.href="/?redirect=1"
```

and then check that parameter

Comment: The way I went about it was easier to handle, but +1 for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The lines of code next to

```
location.href = "/";
```

will not be executed because the browser is navigating to another page.

So you should put your logic in the `/` page (`#button_2` should be in that page).

Answer (score 2):

You're currently trying to execute code after a redirect which isn't possible directly because the code after `location.href = "/"` will never be reached. Once you redirect you've have a fresh page with a clear state.

Your current function can still look like this:

```
$('#button_1').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/somewhere",
        data: {
            //code
        }
    }).done(function () {
            location.href = "/?modal-open=1";
    });    
});
```

As you can see I've added a query parameter to the redirect so we know we were redirected with the intention to open the modal.

For your Root Page (`/`) you will need a script like this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    // check the URL for the modal-open parameter we've just added.
    if(location.search.indexOf('modal-open=1')>=0) {
        $('#button_2').click(); 
    }
});
```

This will check if the parameter is in the URL and trigger the click.

Comment: Thank you, +1 for the good answer. I solved it using my answer, since it was easier to handle

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you redirect a new page you can not access DOM because the page is reloaded. You can send a parameter for do that.

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    //after page load

    var isButtonActive = findGetParameter("isButtonActive");
    if(isButtonActive){
        alert("button_2 activated");
        $('#button_2').click(); 
    }

    $('#button_1').on('click', function () {
        //code
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/somewhere",
            data: {
                //code
            }
        }).done(function () {
            alert("page will be reload. button_2 wil be activated");
            location.href = "/?isButtonActive=true";
        });    
    });

    $('#button_2').on('click', function () {
        alert("button_2 clicked");
    });

});

function findGetParameter(parameterName) {
    var result = null,
        tmp = [];
    location.search
        .substr(1)
        .split("&")
        .forEach(function (item) {
          tmp = item.split("=");
          if (tmp[0] === parameterName) result = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        });
    return result;
}
```